# How to get path to images generated with webpack encore

Tags: image, symfony, webpack, phpmailer, webpack-encore

I have one problem with the images I want to include in my e-mail with phpmailer.
I have tried to use swift mailer with my symfony app but not works I have tried all configuration (all host all ports all encryption etc) during 3 days I have called them etc without any success. It works in local not in remote env...
Anyway, let's go back to my problem.

I use webpack with encore (new way of setting assets for symfony4).
All my images are renamed in the public folder. myimagename.65342324b5.jg I/O myimagename.jpg when I run encore to deploy assets.

The problem is when I want to AddEmbeddedImage

let's supposed I have logo.png in assetsfolder.
When I deploy assets it is renamed logo.536324324V3.png in public images folder.
So when I do

```
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('images/logo.png','mon_logo', 'logo.png');
```

and when I want to refer in my html body of the e-mail to 'mon_logo' the image is not loaded because it is not existing only logo.536324324V3.png.

I have 2 options:

1. First I disable the automatic renaming of my images with webpack
   encore .but I don't know how.
2. Second: I make this script able to recognise logo.png as
   logo.536324324V3.png. Normally it is automatic with the
   manifest.json generated after the assets deployment, but in my case
   the path of my image is in my controller so I cannot specify that it
   is an asset.

   But I cannot do

   ```
     $mail->AddEmbeddedImage(" {{ asset('images/logo.png')}}",'mon_logo', 
       'logo.png');
   ```

   Anyway it makes no sense.

So if you have solutions I'll take it:)

Thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are using the Asset-component as suggested in your second approach, you could just pass in the class `\Symfony\Component\Asset\Packages` which should be available under the service id `assets.packages` and with Symfony 4 likely also under it's fully qualifieed class name. The `Packages` class manages your assets and is also what's used in the Twig_Extension in the `asset()` function.

So in your code you would probably do something like this:

```
$fileUrl = $packages->getUrl('images/logo.png');
```

Comment: I wanted  tried already the $packages->getUrl but when I checked in my package, i didn't see packages class so  I let it down..anyway i will try it now i keep you informed

Comment: Ok so I had the solution since 3 hours but I passed it thinking it could not work as I didn't see packaged but I have packages class in my components... Thank you dbrumann..it's solved!

Comment: damn it works in local but not  in remote. NB I use a https with my remote server, maybe it is the conflict?

Comment: The asset component will use the settings under `framework.assets` for generating the url. So you might want to check the `base_urls:` section. What exactly is the wong url you get on your remote server, is it just the schema (http vs. https) that's wrong?

Comment: I tried to get the UrlPackage with the staticVersionStrategy to change http to https but even with the correct absolute path https the image is not rendered in my email.

Comment: in fact everything works in remote except the image is not embeded. And in local everything works even the image

Comment: It does notwork in dev anymore...I don't understand...When I do an echo of getUrl(myrelativeimagepath) I have the absolute URL (http://localhost/....) and the path is correct..I can type the url in my browser and I am redirected to the image...So maybe the problem is in phpmailer. <br> test